# Hugging Face Transformers do_train and do_eval

Tags: huggingface-transformers, evaluation

I am currently training a MLM and I was wondering what `do_train` and `do_eval` are. It seems to be training fine without those arguments inside my `training_args`.
Do I need to pass them through? Or is it fine if I just don't add them?

I have tried using both but the same thing runs. I don't understand what's the difference really.